# Swift array in dictionary leads to NSCFArray

Tags: arrays, swift, dictionary

I prepare a swift Array in my Watch Interface and send it to the iOS App:

```
@IBAction func buttonGeklickt() {

if WCSession.isSupported() {
    let session = WCSession.defaultSession()
    session.delegate = self
    session.activateSession()

    let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "hh:mm"
    let datumString = dateFormatter.stringFromDate(NSDate())

    var swiftArray = [String]()
    swiftArray.append(datumString)

    var swiftDict = ["a":swiftArray]

    session.transferUserInfo(swiftDict)

}
```

so far so good, on the iOS App the dictionary arrives, but there seems to be something wrong with the Array in the Dictionary:

```
func session(session: WCSession, didReceiveUserInfo userInfo: [String : AnyObject]) {

    print ("seems to be the same Dict = \(userInfo)")

    if let vw = userInfo["a"] as? [String: String] {
        print ("Never called! Here I would expect my array from the watch \(vw)")
    }
}
```

I would expect and like **vw** to hold the same array as **swiftArray** in the watchApp. However it seems to be of type __NSCFArray:
[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cQbY7.png)
So what I'm doing wrong here?

I'm new to Swift, however I'm experienced with Objective C to solve actually every problem I faced in the past years, but this issue seems to be so basic and it's embarrassing that I'm not able to solve it on my own. So help is much appreciated

Answer (score 3):

If I understand your code correctly, you are saving "a" as value of type [String]. But you are trying to read it as [String:String]. Instead of

```
if let vw = userInfo["a"] as? [String: String]
```

try

```
if let vw = userInfo["a"] as? [String]
```

Comment: As I wrote it's embarrassing. Thanks a lot for pointing me in the right direction, your answer is totally correct and solved what I was not able to figure out in hours.